# Plotting categorical column entries as sums in separate stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, figure

I want to essentially recreate this plot that I made in JMP but with R. The values come from a qualitative dataset, where the species groups are entries in a single column. I would like to plot the SpeciesGroup on the x axis, but fill the color in by the Strength, in a stacked bar. I think I need to reorder the data, but can't quite figure out how.

```
df<- data.frame(ID=c(1,2),
                policy=c("Policy A", "Policy B", "Policy C", "Policy D", 
                         "Policy E","Policy F" ),
                SpeciesGroup= c("ray", "ray", "mammal", "mammal", "fish", "reptile"),
                Stength=c("M", "V", "M", "P", "P", "M"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

So far I have tried:

```
ggplot(aes(x=factor(Group), fill = Regulatory_Strength)) +
  geom_bar(mapping = NULL, data = RFMO_Policies, stat = "count",
           position = "stack",  width = .7, binwidth = NULL,
           na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE, inherit.aes = TRUE )+
  labs(title="Policy Directives by Taxa",  x="Directive Type", y = "Count", size = 13 )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=1))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c( "firebrick3","yellow1","dodgerblue1" ), 
                    labels= c("Mandatory","Partial", "Voluntary" ))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1, size= 13))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Regulatory Strength"))
```

Below is the graph I made in JMP that I would like to reproduce:

[image]

Thank you for any help you can offer!!

Comment: Did you try any code yet? Where exactly are you getting stuck? There seem to be a lot of other questions out there about stacked bar plots. I'm not sure I see how this one is different.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, and what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = SpeciesGroup, fill =  Stength))+
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

[image]

**Alternative using `geom_tile`**

To my opinion, as your data are qualitative values, maybe it will make more sense to plot them using `geom_tile`:

```r
library(dplyr)
All_val <- expand(df,SpeciesGroup, Stength)

library(ggplot2)
df %>% mutate(Val = Stength) %>%
    select(SpeciesGroup, Stength, Val) %>%
    full_join(., All_val) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = SpeciesGroup, y = Stength, fill = Val))+
    geom_tile(color = "black")+
    scale_fill_discrete(na.value = "white")+
    geom_text(aes(label = Val))
```

[image]

Comment: yes! oh, this was extremely simple. I think i was just over complicating it. Thank you!!

Comment: Oh, cool! thank you again! that's a cool way to represent it.